# The getter 'onAuthStateChanged' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'. Try importing the library that defines 'onAuthStateChanged'

Tags: flutter, dart

The getter 'onAuthStateChanged' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.
Try importing the library that defines 'onAuthStateChanged', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onAuthStateChanged'
thanks
code is here below..

```
import 'package:brew_crew/model/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService{

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // Create user object based on FirebaseUser
  CurrentUser? _customModelForFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? CurrentUser (uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

   
   // auth changed user stream
  Stream<CurrentUser > get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged // here is the problem
      .map(_customModelForFirebaseUser);
  }
  
  //sin in anon
  Future signInAnon() async{
   try {
  UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
  User? user = result.user;
  return _customModelForFirebaseUser(user!);
}catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}

  }

  //sign in with E-mail and password

  //Register with E-mail and passqord

  //Sign out
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting from firebase 0.18.0, they made slight changes on some classes.

Instead of using _auth.onAuthStateChanged, use _auth.authStateChanges()

Comment: it is 'authStateChanges()' and not 'authStateChanges' because it is available as a method and not a property

Answer (score 0):

this code might resolve all errors for users using latest version (replace NewUser with whatever name of class you are using)

```
Stream<NewUser> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
      .map((User? user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user!)!);
}
```